# Why GAS assembly language can calls a C language global variable directly without any declaration?

Tags: c, linux, arm, gnu-assembler

I'm learning on linux startup code these days, but a small problem is bothering me.

**setup.c** :

```
unsigned int __atags_pointer __initdata;
```

**head-common.S**

```
    .align  2
    .type   __mmap_switched_data, %object
__mmap_switched_data:
    .long   __data_loc                      @ r4
    .long   _sdata                          @ r5
    .long   __bss_start                     @ r6
    .long   _end                            @ r7
    .long   processor_id                    @ r4
    .long   __machine_arch_type             @ r5
    .long   __atags_pointer                 @ r6
    .long   cr_alignment                    @ r7
    .long   init_thread_union + THREAD_START_SP @ sp
    .size   __mmap_switched_data, . - __mmap_switched_data
```

the line `.long   __atags_pointer @ r6` in the **head-common.S** calls the global variable in the **setup.c** without any declaration,
such as `.global  __atags_pointer`. Why does it work ?

Comment: Because GNU assembly isn't C, or any other assembly dialect? I'm not sure there's much of an answer beyond "because [that's just how it is.](https://www.sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Extern.html#Extern)"

Comment: As far as I know, in general , GNU assembly language will make a declaration when it calls a C file global variable.

Comment: Huh? As the docs say, there isn't even such a thing as a declaration. Any referenced symbol that doesn't have a local definition is simply _assumed_ to be external; that's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that:

```
.long  __atags_pointer
```

is a call. It is a pseudo expression. In this case I think it creates a space of 4 bytes and leaves a marker for the linker to fill out the space with the value at link time. From the gas manual:

> '.long' is the same as '.int'.  *Note '.int': Int.
>
> ## 7.44 '.int EXPRESSIONS'
>
> Expect zero or more EXPRESSIONS, of any section, separated by commas.
>   For each expression, emit a number that, at run time, is the value of
>   that expression.  The byte order and bit size of the number depends on
>   what kind of target the assembly is for.

If you compile the file in isolation to get a .o, then run objdump -D on it, I believe you will see the space has all 0's. After you link however, the same space will have an actual number in it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I have found the reason as I replied above.

Answer (score 0):

.globl is how you declare something global so someone ELSE can find it.  In C the lack of a static means that label is global so others can find it.  When you USE a label the assembler and/or linker just puts it in a table of things to find.  Just like in C you ideally declare something as extern, but you dont have to you can declare two global things with the same name and the tools should sort it out to share that resource.

The thing you are talking about was declared global by the C code and assembly is simply trying to use that label by name.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I have found the reason as I replied above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody!  I have found it is how to declare!
The line `.type   __mmap_switched_data, %object` in **the head-common.S**
has made the declaration.   From the gas manual:

5.5.2 Type

The type attribute of a symbol contains relocation (section) information, any flag settings indicating that a symbol is external, and (optionally), other information for linkers and debuggers. The exact format depends on the object-code output format in use.

7.94 .type

This directive is used to set the type of a symbol.

Comment: Huh? Why would the local symbol `__mmap_switched_data` being exported to the linker as a data symbol (i.e. a more specific equivalent to `.global`) have _anything_ to do with the use of the external symbol `__atags_pointer`??